# Node js spawn process hangs

Tags: node.js, spawn

I have a node js application that starts a command in cli.

```
  process = spawn(command, params, options);

  process.stdout.on('data', onLine);
  process.stderr.on('data', onLine);
  process.on('error', onError);
  process.on('close', onClose);
```

It enters `onLine` several times with the output, but then just hangs and does nothing (no exit, no error). What are the possible reasons for that?

If I execute the command in Terminal, everything's fine.
The command is linking a module to react native application (`react-native link`).

Comment: Maybe because you redefine the global value of `process`? `process` is a global variable

Comment: No, I simplified the code. Actually, in my implementation it's `context.process`, and context is my custom object..

Comment: Sudo code isn't going to help us solve your problem. If you want help from this community you have to post all relative code including the functions `online`, `onClose` and `onError`.